How to get Pytubefix to work on ec2 instance?
I have setup an EC2 instance and I am running this code
    try:
        yt = YouTube(video_url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
        transcript = yt.captions['a.en'].generate_srt_captions()
        cleaned_transcript = re.sub(r'\d+\s*\n|\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s*-->\s*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s*\n', '',
                                    transcript)
        cleaned_transcript = " ".join([line.strip() for line in cleaned_transcript.splitlines() if line.strip()])
        return cleaned_transcript
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching transcript for video {video_url}: {str(e)}")
        return None

The code works perfectly when I run locally but in the ec2 server the transcripts return null. I have identical packages installed on each. Would anyone know why this is?

Does EC2 not allow pytubefix

It is possible that YouTube is blocking access from IP addresses assigned to Amazon EC2 instances. Some websites do this to avoid scraping.

This is a pytube bug

It works on local machine though and not on the VM so I think the code is fine
